# Script works as VBS but not HTML

Tags: html, vbscript, active-directory, hta

I have a script that shows a filtered list of what groups a particular AD user is a member of. It works **perfectly fine** as a VBS file, but when imported into either an HTA or HTML file it gives me a *"The search filter cannot be recognized"* error message when running the *"objRecordSet.MoveFirst"* line below.

```
Dim User
Dim DIA
Dim GroupList

DIA = "No"
User = "UserNic"

Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2
Const E_ADS_PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND  = &h8000500D

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE 

objCommand.CommandText = _
    "SELECT memberOf FROM 'LDAP://dc=company,dc=com' WHERE objectCategory='user' And mailnickname='" & User & "'" 
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

objRecordSet.MoveFirst

Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    arrMemberOf = objRecordSet.Fields("memberOf")
        if isArray(objRecordSet.Fields("memberOf")) Then
            For Each x in arrMemberOf
                If InStr(x,"GroupFilter") <> 0 Then
                    Group = x
                    Group = Right(Group,Len(Group)-3)
                    Group = Left(Group,InStr(Group,",")-1)
                    GroupList = Group & vbCrLf & GroupList
                End If
                If InStr(x,"DIA") <> 0 Then DIA = "Yes"
            Next
        End if
    objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop

WScript.Echo GroupList
WScript.echo "DIA: " & DIA
```

I also have another script which is nearly identical that **does** work in HTA/HTML format. This one just shows where an email account is forwarded if at all:

```
Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE 

objCommand.CommandText = _
    "SELECT Name, altRecipient FROM 'LDAP://dc=company,dc=com' WHERE objectCategory='user' And Name='*" & Hosp & "' And altRecipient='*'" 
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

objRecordSet.MoveFirst

Count = 0
Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    Name(Count) = objRecordSet.Fields("Name").Value
    Forward(Count) = objRecordSet.Fields("altRecipient").Value

    arrLines = Split(Forward(Count),",")
    search = Filter(arrLines,"CN=",True,1)
    for each x in search
        Forward(Count) = x
    Next
    Forward(Count) = Replace(Forward(Count),"CN=","")

    objRecordSet.MoveNext
    Count = Count + 1
Loop
```

I can't seem to find any functional differences between each script's *"objRecordSet.MoveFirst"* line.

Please help!

**Edit:**

Same results here. Tried an alternate chunk of code to perform the same actions - works fine as VBS but not HTA:

```
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.CommandText = "<LDAP://dc=domain,dc=com>;" & "(&(objectCategory=Person)(mailnickname=" & User & "));" & "distinguishedName,Name;subtree"
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

intCount = 0
If objRecordSet.EOF Then
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    message = WshShell.Popup ("Unable to find a user with the alias '" & User & "'! Please try again...",, "programname", 0 + 16)
    'Exit Sub
Else
    While NOt objRecordSet.EOF
        intCount = intCount + 1
        objRecordSet.MoveNext
    WEND
        If intCount = 1 Then
            objRecordSet.MoveFirst
            Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objRecordSet.Fields("distinguishedname"))
            Set colGroups = objUser.Groups
            For Each objGroup in colGroups
                Group = objGroup.CN
                GroupList = Group & vbCrLf & GroupList
            Next
        End If
End If

WScript.Echo GroupList
```

Comment: How are you running the `HTML` file, from locally on your machine, or from a server? Browsers have very strong security restrictions in comparison to a `VBS` file being run on your machine

Comment: Both the working and the non-working script are being run from a NAS. The working script works in both HTA and HTML format (I've added both as a trusted site as well as enabled "Access data sources across domains" under the custom security level.

Comment: Very strange... sorry, no idea what is wrong.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a 64-bit OS, try running the 32-bit MSHTA.exe from a command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe C:\YOUR_PATH\yourscript.hta
```

I've had problems with the 64-bit version (**C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe**) failing to support COM/ActiveX interfaces. Windows 7 will open **.HTA** files with the 64-bit version by default.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTA, are you putting your code in side a sub or function?

```
<script language = "VBScript">
Sub Window_Onload
 ##your code here##
End Sub
</script>
```

If not, it could be messing up in trying to Dim USER as a global variable.

Also perfer to rewrite the Echo to something like

```
TextOut.innerHTML = GroupList
</script>
<html><body>
<div id="TextOut"></div>
```