# ADODB reference from an HTA application

Tags: vbscript, adodb, hta

I need an HTA application that shows data from `mdb` using `ADO` technology.

Here's how my code starts:

```
Function getData()
Dim pathname
pathname = "D:\\WP\\ADO\\ADOexamples.mdb"
Dim con 'As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs 'As New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
```

I get an error:

```
Class undefined ADODB.
```

Apparently, it's because I need to include ADODB references. But how do I do it in `.hta` file?

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/11527520/242520, although it does not have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create ADO objects that way in VBScript. Use [`CreateObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcw63t7z%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) instead:

```
pathname = "D:\\WP\\ADO\\ADOexamples.mdb"
Dim con 'As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs 'As New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

Also, VBScript doesn't recognize ADO named constants like `adOpenStatic` or `adLockOptimistic`, so you need to define them yourself:

```
Const adOpenStatic     = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
```

or use their numeric value.